# How to convert StringBuffer to InputStream in Java ME?

Tags: java, java-me, inputstream, midlet, stringbuffer

I'm new in Java and learning Java ME development. I got stuck in this conversion. Please help me to convert `StringBuffer` to `InputStream`. Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

See the class [`ByteArrayInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html).  For example:

```
public static InputStream fromStringBuffer(StringBuffer buf) {
  return new ByteArrayInputStream(buf.toString().getBytes());
}
```

Note that you might want to use an explicit character encoding on the `getBytes()` method, e.g.:

```
return new ByteArrayInputStream(buf.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

(Thanks @g33kz0r)

Comment: `return new ByteArrayInputStream(sb.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));`

Answer (score 8):

See if you can get the `StringBuffer` to a `byte[]` then use a [ByteArrayInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html).

Answer (score 2):

This is the best answer I found on [Java Examples](http://www.java-examples.com/java-stringbuffer-inputstream-example)

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
public class StringBufferToInputStreamExample {
        public static void main(String args[]){
                //create StringBuffer object
                StringBuffer sbf = new StringBuffer("StringBuffer to InputStream Example");
                /*
                 * To convert StringBuffer to InputStream in Java, first get bytes
                 * from StringBuffer after converting it into String object.
                 */
                byte[] bytes = sbf.toString().getBytes();
                /*
                 * Get ByteArrayInputStream from byte array.
                 */
                InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
                System.out.println("StringBuffer converted to InputStream");
        }
}
```